# Working with Videos in Xamarin Android

Tags: video, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-videoview

I am working on videos in Xamarin android. I have to show video from web uri into the VideoView control.But its is not getting displayed. I am getting message "Can't play this video". I have tried all the formats but still the same issue. I am testing it on Nexus 4 emulator with API level 16 and platform 4.1.2. Below is my code

Code in layout

```
 <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/video_frame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <VideoView
                    android:id="@+id/BindableVideoView"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp" />
            </FrameLayout>
```

Code in View

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LessonDetailView);

            var viewModel = (LessonDetailViewModel)ViewModel;

            string LINK = viewModel.VideoUrl.ToString();
            VideoView videoView = (VideoView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.BindableVideoView);
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
            mc.SetAnchorView(videoView);
            mc.SetMediaPlayer(videoView);
            var video = Uri.Parse(LINK);
            videoView.SetMediaController(mc);
            videoView.SetVideoURI(video);
            videoView.Start();

        }
```

I have gone through the links on stack related to this issue but didn't find any solution for my problem.Can someone help and let me know how to play videos in xamarin android.

Comment: Can you post an example of a URL you're trying to play?

Comment: I have tried these url's   https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/91a1/f626b876-b524-4d42-b05f-e4f945fd91a1/Part3IntroductiontoXAML.wmv    http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4